# How can I determine which solutions (and features) are being used in a SharePoint farm?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I inherited a farm and I need to document the solutions/features being used.  At this point, I think I'll need to write some PowerShell or a console app to do this, but just wanted to throw the question out there to make sure I wasn't missing some nifty free utility.

Comment: Do you need more than just the list of solutions and features, which you can see on Central Administration?

Comment: Is this for 2010 or 2007?

Comment: I'm looking for a list of solutions, plus their corresponding features along with where the features are activated.  I need this for both 2007 and 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to get a view of what is being used where is with the stsadm command [enumallwebs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793606%28office.12%29.aspx) using the addtional parameters supplied with the October 2009 Cumulative Update:

```
stsadm -o enumallwebs -includefeatures -includewebparts -includeeventreceivers -includesetupfiles -includecustomlistview
```

Comment: It looks like this is going to be the solution. Thanks SPDoctor

Answer (score 2):

"Documentation Toolkit for SharePoint" can generate a Word document that extensively documents your SharePoint environment.
It is a commercial application, and as such requires licensing; however a 30 days trial is available at:
http://www.spdockit.com/

Comment: My team generated something similar in PowerShell pretty quickly.  The license looks pretty steep all things considered.

Comment: To me the question was about a single use scenario, which is why I expect the 30 days trial to be a valid option for a quick resolution :)

Comment: The DocKit looks useful, but beyond my budget.  Also, the trial version is limited: "* - Trial version only produces limited information in the generated documentation and limits the number of objects that can be compared"

Answer (score 1):

SPM SharePoint Manager - http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: wilco SPDoctor.. relatively new here.. thanks for the link to 'answer'..

Answer (score 0):

Shane Young's got a pretty good blog post on how you can extract every solution package in your SharePoint 2010 farm with a PowerShell script: http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2011/05/05/using-powershell-to-export-all-solutions-from-your-sharepoint-2010-farm-and-other-fun.aspx

John

Comment: I've already extracted the solutions.  I'm trying to determine if they are actually being used.